# How does cv::calcCovarMatrix work?

Tags: opencv

I am calculating the covar and mean using the cv method cv__calcCovarMatrix

First method

```
cv::Mat_<uchar> samples(2,9);  samples << 1,3,2,5,8,7,12,2,4,8,6,9,4,3,3,2,7,7;
cv::Mat_<float> covar, mean;
std::cout << "\nsamples\n" << samples;
cv::calcCovarMatrix( samples, covar, mean, cv::COVAR_NORMAL|cv::COVAR_COLS|cv::COVAR_SCALE, CV_32FC1);
std::cout << "\nMean\n" << mean << "\nCovar\n" << covar << std::endl;
```

Second method

```
cv::Mat_<uchar> x_sample(1,9);  x_sample << 1,3,2,5,8,7,12,2,4;
cv::Mat_<uchar> y_sample(1,9);  y_sample << 8,6,9,4,3,3,2,7,7;
std::vector<cv::Mat> matPtr;
matPtr.push_back(x_sample);
matPtr.push_back(y_sample);
cv::calcCovarMatrix( &matPtr, 9, covar, mean, cv::COVAR_NORMAL, CV_32FC1);
std::cout << "\nMean\n" << mean << "\nCovar\n" << covar << std::endl;
```

1. I was expecting to get an covariance of -8.07 and mean of x = 4.89 and y = 5.44 from the x samples and y samples.

But the answer is -7.17 which is divided by the number of samples and not by samples-1. Why?

samples

```
[  1,   3,   2,   5,   8,   7,  12,   2,   4;
   8,   6,   9,   4,   3,   3,   2,   7,   7]
```

Mean

```
[4.8888888;
 5.4444447]
```

Covar ( I am using CV_COVAR_SCALE ) but covariances are normally divided by samples-1 and not samples.

```
[11.209877, -7.1728396;
 -7.1728396, 5.5802469]
```

2. I am unable to compile the second method. Ofcourse the cv::Mat* is not compatible with std::vector *, but how else should I pass a pointer to an array that contains two matrices.

Comment: You need to store your `x` and `y` points not as rows but columns. The operation is going through columnwise---the mean of 1 and 8 is 4.5, the mean of 3 and 6 is 4.5, 2 and 9 is 5.5, etc.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds :thank you for the hint.. I made a mistake.. it should be cv::COVAR_COLS instead of cv::COVAR_ROWS. But still, I am unable to get the covariance. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `CV_COVAR_NORMAL` without the `CV_COVAR_SCALE` flag and scale them yourself:

```
Mat covar, mean;
cv::calcCovarMatrix(samples, covar, mean, cv::CV_COVAR_NORMAL | CV_COVAR_COLS);
covar = covar / (samples.cols - 1);
```

For point two, note that there are *two* valid calls for `calcCovarMatrix()`. From the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#calccovarmatrix):

```
void calcCovarMatrix(const Mat* samples, int nsamples, Mat& covar, Mat& mean, int flags, int ctype=CV_64F)
void calcCovarMatrix(InputArray samples, OutputArray covar, InputOutputArray mean, int flags, int ctype=CV_64F)
```

In OpenCV, the `InputArray` type is a general classifier for things that are matrix-like. It may or may not accept your vector, but you're using the *first* call in both trials in your code, which expects a `Mat`. A `std::vector` is not a `Mat`, so that's why it won't compile. Try the second call.

Comment: doesnt covar normally already contain the scaling? why shud it be done separately? can you also have a look at the point number 2?

Comment: Only if you use `CV_COVAR_SCALE`, because sometimes you might want to scale yourself. From the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#calccovarmatrix) "By default (if the flag is not specified), the covariance matrix is not scaled ( scale=1 )."

Comment: @infoclogged I edited with a little bit about your point #2. I don't commonly code OpenCV in C++ so it's a guess, but try it out and let me know.